# inverse fourier transform of w*e^w

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have the function

\begin{align}
F^{-1}\{{λe^{-|λ|}}\}
\end{align}

How can we find the inverse Fourier transform?

The correct answer is:

\begin{align}
\frac{-2ix}{π(1+x^2)^2}
\end{align}

Can somebody explain to me what happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you know the answer, it might be easier to find the Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}$, using contour integration for instance.

Comment: Get rid of the modulus by dividing the integral into positive and negative parts and do the integration. Don't fret, I am sure you can easily do it.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathcal F\{f(x)\}=\hat{f}(\lambda)=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-i\lambda x}\, dx
$$

The Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-a|x|}$ is $\hat{f}(\lambda)=\frac{2a}{a^2 + \lambda^2} $ and then for the duality property $\mathcal F\{\hat{f}(x)\}= 2\pi f(-\lambda)$ we have $$\mathcal F\left\{\frac{2a}{a^2 + x^2} \right\}=2\pi e^{-a|-\lambda|}$$
and for the differentiation property $\mathcal F\{{f'}(x)\}=i\lambda \hat{f}(\lambda)$, and then
$$
\mathcal F\left\{\left(\frac{2a}{a^2 + x^2}\right)'\right\}=\mathcal F\left\{-\frac{4ax}{(a^2 + x^2)^2}\right\}=i\lambda \left(2\pi e^{-a|-\lambda|}\right)
$$
Thus we have
$$
\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{\lambda e^{-a|\lambda|}\right\}=\frac{4ax}{2\pi i(a^2 + x^2)^2}=\frac{-2iax}{\pi (a^2 + x^2)^2}
$$
and for $a=1$
$$
\mathcal F^{-1}\left\{\lambda e^{-|\lambda|}\right\}=-\frac{2ix}{\pi (1 + x^2)^2}
$$